# MacOS Xのウインドウ巡回を逆に巡回するには？

Tags: macos

MacOS X（Yosemite）で`Cmd+F1`キーを押すと
複数のウインドウが立ち上がっているsafariやfinderなどで
ウインドウを巡回させることができますが

これを逆順に巡回させる方法はありますでしょうか。
最終的にCmd+Opt+<とCmd+Opt+>でウインドウを自由に切り替えれたら
便利だなと思っています。

サードパーティ製のアプリを利用して
実現する方法などでもかまいません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cmd + Shift + F1`を使用するのはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: Shiftで逆巡回だったのですね。ありがとうございましたm(_ _)m

Comment: @hojo だいたいは Shift で逆向きになりますね。アプリケーション切替の ⌘-Tab も ⌘-Shift-Tab で逆循環になります。